# Asp.NET MVC Autofac Inject Dependence non-controller class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

All classes that inherit from controller have already inserted the dependencies, but I do not know how to inject those who do not inherit from contoller.

in the example below the **SendEmailAndLog()** method waits for the **ILoggerService** interface to be injected. but I do not know how to do this.

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{

   SendEmailHelper sendEmailHelper = new SendEmailHelper();
    await sendEmailHelper.SendEmailAndLog(user, "Task", user.UserName, UserManager, loggerService);

}
```

this task is called the method **Application_Start()** on Global.asax.cs

I created a constructor to receive this service as a parameter, this is working for the methods within the controllers that call the Class Emailservice. However there are classes that do not inherit from controller so I do not know how to inject.

My Service is:

```
public interface ILoggerService
    {
        void Error(ExceptionLogger exception);
        void SaveLog();
    }

    public class LoggerService : ILoggerService
    {
        private readonly ILoggerRepository loggerRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;


        public LoggerService(ILoggerRepository loggerRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.loggerRepository = loggerRepository;
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public void Error(ExceptionLogger exception)
        {
            loggerRepository.Error(exception);
        }

        public void SaveLog()
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }


    }
```